# How to subscribe a topic in WSO2 MB 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, publish-subscribe, messagebroker, jms-topic, wso2-message-broker

I've been working with the `WSO2 Message Broker` for a while and I clearly understood the way of publishing and consuming a message to and from a queue as well topics. According to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Managing+Topics+and+Sub+Topics), it has not been mentioned anywhere how could I subscribe to a particular topic from the management console where as this particular [section](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Managing+Durable+Topic+Subscriptions) talks about creating durable subscriptions from the code level.

But then the [older](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Managing+Topics+and+Subscriptions) version of this has a way to subscribe from the console it self. Am i missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using WSO2 MB 2.2.0 is not advisable since it is a deprecated release.

Regarding the Problem,
Subscribing to a particular topic from the management console is not a valid use case since if you subscribe to a relevant topic using the management console to which consumer the messages should be pushed to?

The subscribing you mentioned in  MB 2.2.0 is to subscribe to a particular topic from the management console for WS-Eventing where you can subscribe a topic to a given event sink.

WSO2 MB no longer support this.

Thanks,
Kamidu.

Comment: Which means the newer version of MB doesn't support WS-Eventing? So i could only subscribe to a topic through a jms client? Not through the management console is it?

Comment: You need to understand the concept of subscribe to a topic which can be only possible with a client.
In the previous release subscribe to the event sink means the messages in the given topic will be forward to the given url which is a event sink.
So its not about subscribing to a topic as a client. 
If you need more help please use the dev@wso2.org mail with the details.